# web service call with more than one parameter

Tags: web-services, .net

In my app, I am calling .Net soap based webservices.
My web service call function is :

```
function CallService5() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://10.0.2.2:51434/Service1.asmx/GetAllTableStatus",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
        });
    }
```

How can i add more than one parameter..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use like this

```
var firstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
var lastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value;
data : "{'firstName':firstName,'lastName':lastName}"
```

Comment: Okies and how can i get the values of that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters as query string in the url part of service

```
"http://10.0.2.2:51434/Service1.asmx/GetAllTableStatus?para =val"
```

Comment: Ideally it must, does your method GetAllTableStatus accepts parameters ? The parameter name will come at place of Para and value will come at place of val

Answer (score 0):

You read the following articles: 
it gives good solutions..

http://elegantcode.com/2009/02/21/javascript-arrays-via-jquery-ajax-to-an-aspnet-webmethod/

http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/